# No records selected in combobox after validation

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

I use [Laravel Collective](https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.4/html) for my forms,
I using a combobox for show list of roles.

this is my code:

```
{!! Form::model($user, ['route' => ['admin.users', $user->id], 'method' => 'put', 'class' => 'form-horizontal', 'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data']) !!}
    {!! Form::select('roles[]', $r_list, null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'multiple' => true]) !!}
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

When the page load for first time, all values will select witouht any problem, but after returning to form with validation no items selected in list.

what should I do?

Comment: what's your validator's output after validation ? i.e. `$validator->getData()`

Comment: @shyammakwana.me `{{ dump($validator->getData()) }}` return `Undefined variable: validator`

Comment: well `$validator` is just an example, you need to replace your variable there.

Comment: @shyammakwana.me Oh, sorry, but I don't know what is the returned variable name, I use Request file for validation and use `$errors` for validating errors

Comment: can you add the html rendered from your Form::select() ?  I suspect using roles[] as the name of your select element may cause an issue.

Comment: @DomDaFonte I cannot understand your mean exactly, but for testing I removed the brackets `[]` from end of roles, but when user selected multiple items, values cannot send

Comment: Right click on your page in a browser, view source and post the output from your blade commands.  Also Var_dump the variable you are using to create the select (i.e. Dd($r_list);)